# reverse of astro `:global(<css-rule>)`? i.e. `:scoped(.my-class) b {}` inside `<script is:global>`?

Tags: astrojs

In astro, I can make a style declaration like this:

```html
<div class="container"><slot></slot></div>
<style>
  .container {
    & :global(h1) {
      font-size: 2em;
    }
    & :global(h2) {
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Now, to save some typing, what I'd rather do is:

```html
<div class="container"><slot></slot></div>
<style is:global>
  :scoped(.container) {
    & h1 {
      font-size: 2em;
    }
    & h2 {
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Is that possible somehow? is there any such modifier in the `is:global` scope?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this were possible. Probably the contents of `<style is:global>` are just output verbatim, so you cannot do much smart stuff in there. But why would you do `.container :global(h1)` anyway instead of just `.container h1` ?

Comment: Because `.container h1` won't affect an `h1` in my container that comes from the content in `<slot>`, whereas `.container :global(h1)` will.

Comment: I've wanted to do something similar, but haven't found a way. I was hoping something like `.container :global({ h1 {...} h2 {...} })` might work, but naturally it doesn't.

Comment: @jdunning It's perfectly possible to do this, just not with the convenience I wanted. 

My first example is valid and works. The ampersands are optional.